# What is the datatype of the iterate values returned by `range`?

Tags: go

```golang
type Student struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    data := make([]*Student, 0)

    src := []Student{
        Student{Name: "allen", Age: 30},
        Student{Name: "tom", Age: 33},
    }

    for _, m := range src {
        data = append(data, &m) // notice point!!!
    }

    for _, s := range data {
        fmt.Println(*s)
    }
}
```

Why does this piece of code work in Go? The output is kind of in contrast to the expected, which is below.

```
{tom 33}
{tom 33}
```

instead of

```
{allen 30}
{tom 33}
```

An explanation I found is that `m` is a fixed pointer, thus every time `append(data,&m)` just appends the address of `m`, which remains the same during iterations.

However, according to this explanation, `m` seems to be of `*Student`, so `&m` is of `**Student`, but how can a value(`&m`) of `**Student` be appended into an array of `[]*Student`?

Answer (score 1):

When ranging over a slice, two values are returned for each iteration. The first is the index, and the second is a copy of the element at that index.

So, it have the value of the array/slice that you are iterating.

In your case, the value is a `Student` struct

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use introspection to find out what `m` is. Also, you could declare it (`var m ...`) before the loop as an experiment.

Now, you write "An explanation I found is that m is a fixed pointer". Firstly, I'm not sure what you mean with "fixed pointer" nor do I think that you do. What is fixed (or constant) is the address of `m`. The conclusion is "thus every time `append(data,&m)` just appends the address of `m`", which is exactly what's happening. However, your assumption that "`m` seems to be of `*Student`" is flawed, `m` is of type `Student` instead, simple as that.

Comment: Sorry that I used the wrong term `fixed point`, by which I meant a pointer that points to different memory addresses during the iteration. Thanks to the link shared by @kojan abzah, I understand it.

Comment: I got used to C and Rust, so it confuses me that in Go, references and pointers seem to be mixed up in a not so clear way. The issue is that `m` in the `range` loop acts like a pointer pointing to a struct(and indeed functionally it just a pointer), but is a reference of the type of the struct. If we rewrite the code in C, we can see `m` is a pointer `*Student`, and thus clearly `&m` is `**Student`, and the code behaves just like what you expect because pointers and pointers of pointers are used.

Comment: In addition to this ambiguous separation of references from pointers, type inference makes it harder to distinguish references and pointers. The pointer example of [iterating-over-slices-in-go](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2013/09/iterating-over-slices-in-go.html) illustrates how to modify my code to make it behave like I expected, but also shows this ambiguity. If we rewrite the code in Rust, we can see that Rust enforces stricter boundaries of references and pointers and also data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its related to the fact the in Go, everything is passed by value.

```
m := range src
```

`m` is always the same reference and its value is updated. 
A simple way to see it is to print the address

```
for _, m := range src {
    // ---
    p := &m
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", p)
    // ---
    data = append(data, &m) // notice point!!!
}
```

Great post explaining your exact question can be found here [iterating-over-slices-in-go](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2013/09/iterating-over-slices-in-go.html)